# how to add values to dropdownlist box fromtextbox

Tags: asp.net

I have `List<int> items = new List<int>();`.

And in the UI I have a textbox that I am entering and ListItem.

When I enter the value in textbox I need to add values to the listitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN, [How to: Add Items in List Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14atsyf5(v=VS.85).aspx).

```
items.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value"));
```